# Run TestNG tests from one of the modules in multi module maven project

Tags: testng, multi-module

I have a multimodule maven project consisting of 3 modules:

- **framework** (no src/tests folder) in pom.xml no dependencies
- **page-objects** (no src/tests folder) pom.xml contains dependency on framework module
- **tests** (no src/main folder)pom.xml contains dependency on framework module and page-objects module

All tests classes and testng.xml suite are located in module **tests**.

When i try to run single test or testng suite in Intelij (or with mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=XXX) i am getting following error

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/IInvokedMethodListener2
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:801)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:699)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:622)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:580)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(ServiceLoader.java:1209)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1220)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1264)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1299)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1384)
    at org.testng.TestNG.addServiceLoaderListeners(TestNG.java:961)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeConfiguration(TestNG.java:898)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeEverything(TestNG.java:988)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:999)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at om.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:110)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener2
```

I searched and found that creating run configurations may help so I created run configuration and selected "In single module" radio and my tests module, but it did not help.

What is the reason of this error?